# Admin login is not working

Tags: php, web

I have a admin login script which starts the session after successful login, but the problem is that it logs us in correctly and redirects us to index.php but at index.php it says your login session is not recorded on the database.

```
    <?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: admin_login.php"); 
    exit();
}
// Be sure to check that this manager SESSION value is in fact in the database
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
// Run mySQL query to be sure that this person is an admin and that their password session var equals the database information
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
// ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
$existCount = @mysqli_num_rows($conn,$sql); // count the row nums
if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
     exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Store Admin Area</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent"><br />
    <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
      <h2>Hello store manager, what would you like to do today?</h2>
      <p><a href="inventory_list.php">Manage Inventory</a><br />
      <a href="#">Manage Blah Blah </a></p>
    </div>
    <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  </div>
  <?php include_once("../template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My admin_login.php

```
    <?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: index.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Parse the log in form if the user has filled it out and pressed "Log In"
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {

    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    // ------- MAKE SURE PERSON EXISTS IN DATABASE ---------
    $existCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
         }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         header("location: index.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin Log In </title>

</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">

  <div id="pageContent"><br />
    <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
      <h2>Please Log In To Manage the Store</h2>
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="admin_login.php">
        User Name:<br />
          <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
        <br /><br />
        Password:<br />
       <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />

         <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />

      </form>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
    </div>
    <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  </div>
  <?php include_once("../template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you really have spaces BEFORE the `<?php` tag, remove them, they will get sent to the browser, thus destroying your ability to start a session, as headers will already have been sent

Comment: If you look in your PHP Error Log you will probably see messages saying just that

Comment: if you need to cleanse data, I suggest clensing it BEFORE you store it in the SESSION and not when you get it out of the session. But regardless please read [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

All database wrote in Session is by your code, not user input, I do not think you need regEx on it while password may contain special character, this will gone fail.

Just replace

`$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); // filter everything but numbers and letters`

with

`$managerID = $_SESSION["id"]);
$manager =  $_SESSION["manager"]);
$password = $_SESSION["password"]);`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /storage/ssd3/410/2129410/public_html/storeadmin/admin_login.php on line 19

Comment: @AhadAmanHunzai Updated, easier to understand

Comment: Replace  them with what?

Comment: still error bro :/

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: username in /storage/ssd3/410/2129410/public_html/storeadmin/admin_login.php on line 16 Notice: Undefined index: password in /storage/ssd3/410/2129410/public_html/storeadmin/admin_login.php on line 17